# How could I find regression count from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I get one special task that requires me to account for the number of regression test from a table. The table is like:

```
|test |status|
|test1| pass |
|test2| fail |
|test3| fail |
|test4| fail |
|test5| pass |
|test6| fail |
...
```

The definition of regression count is when there is a transition from pass to fail, regression count++. So the count of regression for the table above will be 2.
And now I have no idea how to finish that task using T-SQL. Could I use T-SQL to handle it, or I need to use other methods such as writing a Python script?

Comment: . . Your question presupposed an *ordering* to the rows.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely agree with the solution provided by Gordon. Assuming number part of the test column be used for the purpose of ordering, you can get the desired result using -

```
select count(1)
from (select t.*, lead(status) over (order by  cast(substring(test,5,len(test)+1-5) as int)) as next_status
       from t
     ) t
where status = 'pass' and coalesce(next_status,'-') = 'fail';
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, to answer your question, I need to assume there is an ordering column of some sort.

With such a column, simply use `lead()` or `lag()`:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*, lead(status) over (order by <ordering column>) as next_status
      from t
     ) t
where status = 'pass' and next_status = 'fail';
```

It is possible in your data that the ordering column is in fact `test`, but that is not clear.

Comment: Ordering by `test` would put `'test11'` between `'test1'` and `'test2'`. That also isn't clear.

Comment: If the ordering column is test then while ordering we should only consider the number part of the column test & in that case we can use -       
    cast(substring(test,5,len(test)+1-5) as int)
        in order to extract the number part from the column test